# Backup Tool Not Working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, backup, duplicity

I'm completely new to Linux OS environment & wanted to experiment a bit.

After installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 TLS (& productivity software), I tried back-up my system w/ the Backup software provided

I got my first error:
**Failed to execute child process "duplicity" (No such file or directory).**

I read on this forum that I had to install Duplicity to get it to work.

So, I ran this command:

```
sudo apt install duplicity
```

and got another error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>
> **E: Unable to locate package deja-dup-backend-gvfs**

Help would be appreciated before I sink down an error rabbit hole

Was also told to run these:

```
apt-cache policy | egrep -vi translat
```

> **Package files:**
>
> **100 /var/lib/dpkg/status**
>
> **release a=now**
>
> **Package files:**

```
apt-cache policy duplicity
```

> **duplicity:**
>
> **Installed: (none)**
>
> **Candidate: (none)**
>
> **Version table:**

Thanks Much!

Comment: Please edit your question and show `apt-cache policy | egrep -vi translat` and `apt-cache policy duplicity`

Comment: Done.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something odd is going on. Is your system a new install, not an upgrade? Because `deja-dup-backend-gvfs` does not appear to be an 18.04 package (it is in xenial).  It is also concerning that there is no candidate for `duplicity`. I fear something is deeply wrong with your system's apt setup.

Comment: I agree with @OrganicMarble 's assessment.  Please post the output of `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`  but be prepared to reinstall (*Remember how many times you've reinstalled Windows before you got it right?  You're up the same learning curve, but with help now...)* **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Where is your sources.list gone?

create the file`/etc/apt/sources.list` with following content.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

Then update package information from all configured sources with

`sudo apt update`

```
sudo apt install duplicity
```

Comment: ** (gedit:29979): WARNING **: 20:24:55.295: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

Comment: Seemed to resolve the issue, but I got the above error when editing the the sources.list file with gedit

Comment: Only, warnings if program works, nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this particular issue by uninstalling the respectful built-in version on deja-dup and replace it with corresponding snap version. Seems worked for me at least. Source: [launchpad comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1747646/comments/28)

```
sudo apt remove deja-dup

snap install deja-dup --classic
```

Comment: this is not working =(